# Select all rows from a table with an indication of existence in another table using mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have three tables

```
Table a
+-----+-------+
| aid | value |
+-----+-------+
|   1 | A     |
|   2 | B     |
|   3 | C     |
|   4 | D     |
+-----+-------+

Table b
+-----+------+
| bid | name |
+-----+------+
|   1 | A    |
|   2 | B    |
|   3 | C    |
+-----+------+

Table ba (mapping of table a and table b)
+-----+-----+
| bid | aid |
+-----+-----+
|   1 | 1   |
|   2 | 1   |
|   3 | 1   |
|   3 | 2   |
|   1 | 3   |
|   2 | 3   |
|   2 | 4   |
+-----+-----+
```

From these tables I want a query like

```
SELECT aid, mapped('true'-if(aid exist in ba) 'false'-otherwise) 
FROM a 
     JOIN b 
     JOIN ba 
WHERE bid=1
```

to get a result from where I can generate a list

```
(when bid=1)
A-mapped
B-not mapped
C-mapped
D-not mapped

(when bid=2)
A-mapped
B-not mapped
C-mapped
D-mapped

(when bid=3)
A-mapped
B-mapped
C-not mapped
D-not mapped
```

Right now I am generating the list in a while loop for all the rows of table 'a' and inside the loop a query is executed for each iteration to check the existence in table 'ba'.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is supposed to be table b independent:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', a.value,  IF(ba.aid IS NULL, "-not mapped", "-mapped"))
FROM a LEFT JOIN ba ON a.aid = ba.aid AND ba.bid = 1
ORDER BY a.aid
```

Note: I took "a" table as the base table since your samples included all values from "a" table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it surely does.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  You reference `ba.bid` without ever even mentioning that table in your query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen re-read my query please - especially FROM a LEFT JOIN ba  part that mentions that table you are referring. Anyways, I created tables as in the question and built my query in real. It surely works and fulfills what requested in the question.

Comment: @Bishwa - you don't need join on "b" table since "ba" already contains "bid". That's what I meant in my answer. And yes, this surely works as you need, except you don't have to use CONCAT_WS. I just used it to provide exactly your sample results. You can instead return 1 or 0 with IF statement in it. Let me know if you have further questions on my answer.

Comment: No offense to you at all, but if I posted your query I would get nailed by many people.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky question, but the difficult part is in figuring out how to formulate the query.  Once that is out of the way, it is downhill from there.  One approach is to use a cross join between the A and B tables to obtain all possible mappings.  Then `LEFT JOIN` to the mapping table to determine which pairs are being mapped and which are not.  Try the following query:

```
SELECT tb.bid, ta.value,
       CASE WHEN ba.bid IS NOT NULL THEN 'mapped' ELSE 'not mapped' END AS label
FROM tb INNER JOIN ta     -- cross join to obtain all bid/aid pairs
LEFT JOIN ba              -- to determine which pairs are mapped/not mapped
    ON ta.aid = ba.aid AND tb.bid = ba.bid
ORDER BY tb.bid, ta.value
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle